# Apache ranger updating permissions via third party

Tags: authorization, apache-ranger

Im trying to see if there is a possiblity to update permissions on `apache ranger` by user access via a third party that contains his permissions.
for example:
A user tries to access a hive table protected by a tag policy, before the ranger checks for his priviliges he runs a script\api call to check with a third party if that user indeed has access (incase he recently recieved access from a diffrent party)

Is there such a possiblity in Ranger or anything similar to it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

@coading_potato Ranger does not enforce policies, Let's talk about HDFS, so in this case, Namenode will fetch policies from Ranger Admin and keep a copy of the policies in policaycache.json file. Each time any hdfs operation happens, namenode will read the policies from policaycache.json file.

If you take down the ranger, policies will still work.

About automating for creation of policies, you can certainly use scripts but that would not be a good practice.

I understand from question that you have tag based policies, so I would suggest tags and groups for creating policies. This will certainly reduce your work.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, tags and groups are indeed the direction im going, however i was wondering if its possible to run a script before lets say Namenode grabs the policies from ranger inorder to check/update users belonging to certain groups via third party?

Comment: Right now im doing a synchronous script that updates groups and policies and looking for ways to reduce script runtime

Comment: @coding_potato Certainly, you can reduce the runtime, you can make your script to read the policycache file, which is in jason format, with #jq utility, you can check if certain user has access to certain resources, there will be a tag metadata in same location where we have policyache file. /etc/ranger/<clustername_servicename>/policycache